# SQL order by needs to check if DATETIME2 is not null then return them first and after order by id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables and I have trouble figuring out how to do the order by statement to fit my needs.
Basically if the `FeaturedUntil` column if greater than now then these should be returned first ordered by the `PurchasedAt` column. Most recent purchases should be first. After these everything should be ordered by the item `Id` column descending.

**Create Table Script**

```
create table Items(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(200) null,
) 

create table Feature(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PurchasedAt] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [FeaturedUntil] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
)
```

**Insert Script**

```
insert into Items(Name) values ('test1')
insert into Feature(PurchasedAt, FeaturedUntil, ItemId) values (dateadd(day, -3, getdate()), dateadd(month, 1, getdate()), @@IDENTITY)
insert into Items(Name) values ('test2')
insert into Feature(PurchasedAt, FeaturedUntil, ItemId) values (dateadd(day, -2, getdate()), dateadd(month, 1, getdate()), @@IDENTITY)
insert into Items(Name) values ('test3')
insert into Feature(PurchasedAt, FeaturedUntil, ItemId) values (dateadd(day, -1, getdate()), dateadd(month, -1, getdate()), @@IDENTITY)
insert into Items(Name) values ('test4')
```

**Select Script**

```
select * 
from Items i 
left join Feature f on i.Id = f.ItemId
order by 
case when f.FeaturedUntil is not null THEN f.PurchasedAt
else  i.Id 
end
```

The `select` should return test2 first as it's `FeaturedUntil` is greater than now and it is the most recently purchased, second row should be test1 as it is bought before test2. After these should be test4 and last one is test3, because these have no joining `Feature` table data or the `FeatureUntil` is not greater than now and these are order by their `Item.Id` descending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   items i
       LEFT JOIN feature f
              ON i.id = f.itemid
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN f.featureduntil > getdate THEN purchasedat
            ELSE '19000101'
          END DESC,
          id DESC
```

You need to order this in descending in order to get the most recent purchase first; the ID sort will still occur, so if you have two PurchasedAt's that are the same, it would sort those 2 by ID.

Comment: `Id` needs to be ordered descending as well, but the `PurchasedAt` is never going to be the same so if you put the `Id desc` at the end, it returns the correct results.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that - you're right, you did ask for ID desc but as you stated, adding DESC will fix that oversight. I'll edit the answer for posterity :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've told us, I *think* this might be what you're after:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN FeaturedUntil > GETDATE THEN PurchasedAt ELSE '99991231' END ASC, --Future features first, and in date order
                                                                                     --(past have a silly in future date, so always last
         Id; --Then ID
```

Comment: Works as expected for me, @Sugafree. [db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9c0d86d331c0a37a9ce43e6cd8d4f2b2). if you don't explain why, I can't help you.

Comment: I appreciate your help Larnu. The reason why I did not explain it, because Sean already answered it correctly. Items with `FeaturedUntil` greater than now should be ordered descending, meaning the most recently bought one should be first (test2). Yours is ordered ascending as well as the `Id` column order was incorrect too. I have explained in the question, the correct result order should be test2, test1, test4, test3

Comment: That isn't what you say in your question, actually, @Sugafree : *"should be returned first ordered by the PurchasedAt column. **Most recent purchases should be first.** That doesn't actually mean descending or Ascending. A future date might be ordered *before* a past date. That would actually be the absolute value between the current date and time and the date of the column.

Comment: I see what you mean, Larnu, with 'most recent to now' meaning desc in the past and asc with future dated items. I think that the confusion is that 'most recent' to OP meant newest to oldest whereas you took it literally with the absolute value notion. I didn't even think about that when I answered!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
select *,  case when f.FeaturedUntil is not null THEN f.PurchasedAt else NULL end AS PurchasedAtNew
from Items i 
left join Feature f on i.Id = f.ItemId
order by PurchasedAtNew desc, i.Id
```